# How to average random numbers in java?

Tags: java, random

thanks in advance for any help I'm in an intro to java class and our home work was to generate 10 random numbers between 1&50 which I got and then average the generated numbers. I can't figure out how to average them here's what I have. Is there a way to store each random number as a variable?

```
public class randomNumberGen
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
         Random r=new Random();

         for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
             System.out.println(r.nextInt(50));
             System.out.println();
              int average = (i/4);

              System.out.println("your average is"+average);

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: like for every average, sum and divide by amount of items.

Comment: Hint: what is `String [] args`? But really there is no need to store the data, simply calculate the [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: average = i/4 ????

Comment: Hint 1: To both print and calculate average, you'll be using each random value twice, so you need to assign it to a variable. --- Hint 2: Formula for average is `sum(values) / count(values)`. You know the count is 10, so all you need to do is sum them.

Comment: first define insert two parameters `sum = 0` and `count = 0` , then calculate average with them

Comment: `r.nextInt(50)` produces values between 1 and 50 ? I don't think so...

Comment: you must calculate it from updated `sum` and `count`

Comment: Incidentally, your code is wrong - [`Random.nextInt(bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) returns a value `[0,bound)` so in your case between `0` and `49` and not between `1` and `50` as required.

Comment: @fabian `r.nextInt(50)` produces numbers between [0 .. 49]

Answer (score 3):

use streams with java 8

```
 final int numberOfRandom = 10;
 final int min = 0;
 final int max = 50;
 final Random random = new Random();

 System.out.println("The ave is: "+random.ints(min, max).limit(numberOfRandom).average());
```

Comment: I would use `DoubleStream.average()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Pretty good!! I will defenetly consider that!
Thns a lot :)

Comment: In this case `IntStream.average()` is more appropriate than DoubleStream ;)

Comment: I think this is completely not the point. He is starting to learn Java, and this is his homework. I see no point neither on giving the code to copy/paste nor on using "plug and play" methods. This answeris perfect for the algorithm part, but not for the question being made.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to replace "r.nextInt(50)" for "r.nextInt(50) + 1" because r.nextInt(n) returns a number between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive). Then, you know that an average is just a sum of n values divided by n. What you can do is just declare a "total" variable initialized to 0 before the loop. On each iteration you add to this variable the random value generated by r.nextInt(50). After the loop you can just divide the total by 10 so you get the average.

PS: it's a good practice to don't use "magic numbers", so it would be perfect (and luckily your teacher will have it in count) if you declare a constant for the number of iterations and then use it both in the loop condition and in the average calculation. Like this, if you have to make it for 100 numbers you only have to change the constant value from 10 to 100 instead of replacing two 10's por two 100's. Also this gives you the chance to give semantic value to these numbers, because now they will be "AMOUNT_OF_NUMBERS = 10" instead of just "10".

Answer (score 0):

**Average = Sum of numbers / amount of numbers**

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    sum += r.nextInt(50) +1; //nextInt 50 produces value 0 to 49 so you add 1 to get 1 to 50 OR as suggested in the comments sum/10d
}
System.out.println("Average is: " + sum/10) // If you want the result in double (with decimals) just write sum*1.0/10
```

**You could also do the same with a while loop.**

```
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(i < 10){
        sum += r.nextInt(50) +1;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Average is: " + sum*1.0/i);
```

**Or even shorter with lambda expressions:** (/java 8 streams)

```
OptionalDouble average = IntStream.range(1, 10).map(x-> x = r.nextInt(50) +1).average();
System.out.println("Average is "+ average.getAsDouble());

.map(x-> x = r.nextInt(50) +1) // maps (changes) each value from 1 to 10 to a random number between 1 and 50
.average(); // calculates the average.
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not helpful.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I know it's not good practice to solve homework for others, but this *is* a valid solution. So why downvote!?

Comment: @f1sh Because giving away solution will encourage homework trolls. There are already enough of those around.

Comment: @Andreas I'm very aware of that, but at least OP has some code to show. And I refuse to downvote correct code.

Comment: for complex problems you can write the code , it's just a simple problem ...
you must write the idea ...
i he/she can't write this simple code , never can write complex codes

Comment: Write `sum/10d` instead of `sum*1.0/10` in case floating point values should be the result.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I am aware of the learning process behind this. I also know this is a very simple task. But working code is a valid answer, no matter the politics behind it. What's worse than answering homework questions is to downvote correct answers just because you personally don't agree with them.

Answer (score 0):

Like every average, it's `sum of elements / amount of elements`. So let's apply it here:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomNumberGen
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        double sum = 0; // is double so to prevent int division later on
        int amount = 10;
        int upperBound = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            int next = r.nextInt(upperBound) + 1; // creates a random int in [1,50]
            System.out.println(next);

            sum += next; // accumulate sum of all random numbers
        }

        System.out.println("Your average is: " + (sum/amount));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store variables outside of the loop to store both the total amount of numbers generated as well as the sum of those numbers. After the loop completes, divide the sum by the total amount of numbers.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Random r=new Random();
    double sum = 0;
    int totalNums;

    for (totalNums=1;totalNums<=10;totalNums++){
        int randomNum = r.nextInt(50);
        sum += randomNum;
        System.out.println(randomNum);
    }

    double average = sum/totalNums;
    System.out.println("your average is: "+average);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply create a variable `sum` starting at zero that you increment at each iteration. After the loop, simply divide by the number of elements..

Comment: i would store the number of elements to a constant/variable so you don't have to put the ``10`` in there twice.

Comment: `nextInt(50)` does *not* generate a random number between 1 and 50.

Answer (score -1):

Average means you should add everything up and devide it by the number of elements (50).

```
import java.util.Random;
class Homework {
    public static final Random RANDOM = Random(); // never regenerate randoms
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final int N = 50;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
             sum += RANDOM.nextInt(50)+1;
        }
        System.out.println("Avg: "+ sum / (float) N);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. Try to learn from it not just C+P.

Ps: Friggin annoying to write code on a phone.

Comment: Loop over numbers to sample numbers. Loop over numbers to sum numbers. This is logically rather ... poor.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know. Just thought that if he can't do the task himself he may not be an awesome programmer who will just take a Java8-Stream one liner and be ok.

Comment: Then why post it??

Comment: @BoristheSpider Explanation above.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you dismissing the _logic_ of the code because you were writing it on a phone? That makes no sense.

Comment: @BoristheSpider No. It's a pretty simple task. If the OP can't get it to work I'll better break the problem down (first generate numbers, then sum them, then do the average) instead of doing something he will not understand.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more. This answer shows the sort of lack of "thinking it through" logic that we try and train _out of_ new programmers. You need need a sum of numbers there is absolutely no reason to store all the numbers. This is waste of space and time - the two things that are scarce in programs.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Disagree with the space thing. Every modern Computer should have that 200 bytes of memory.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Are you ok now?